# Table text not displaying in IE7

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I'm currently using PrimeFaces to create a table containing a list of names and for some reason the text is not displaying for one of my pages in IE7.  I have the same code in other pages but for some reason only this segment is not being displayed

```
    <p:panel id="DisplayTable" style="width: 635px; align:center; border-style:none;">
        <p:dataTable id="authorTbl" value="#{bean.authors}" 
          var="name" scrollable="true" height="100"
          style="font-size: 12px; align: center;z-index:10" emptyMessage="">
          <p:column style="width: 150px;">
            <f:facet name="header">
              <h:outputText value="Last" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{name.lastName}" style="z-index:100;color:black" />
          </p:column>

          <p:column style="width: 150px;">
            <f:facet name="header">
              <h:outputText value="First" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{name.firstName}" styleClass="tblColumnText"/>
          </p:column>

          <p:column style="width: 10px;">
            <f:facet name="header">
              <h:outputText value="MI" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{name.middleName}" styleClass="tblColumnText"/>
          </p:column>

          <p:column style="width: 150px;">
            <f:facet name="header">
              <h:outputText value="Title/Suffix" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText size="4" value="#{name.prefix}" styleClass="tblColumnText"/>
          </p:column>
          <p:column style="width: 60px; align:center;">
            <f:facet name="header">
              <h:outputText value="Action" />
            </f:facet>
            <p:commandButton value="Remove"
              action="#{bean.removeAuthor(name)}"
              disabled="#{bean.sf298ReadOnly}"
              update="Form:authorTbl" style="align: center;" />
          </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>
      </p:panel>
```

When I highlight over the text area I'm unable to see the text.
When I highlight over the text and copy it to notepad I can see the text being displayed.

I originally thought it was a z-index issue but after playing around with increasing z-index I was unable to reach a solution.

Comment: it's a hasLayout issue. apply zoom:1, position:relative, etc to you problematic element.

Comment: If the above comment doesn't work for you, please provide a sample of the actual HTML output, preferably using [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/).

Comment: @easwee  that works great!!!!  I'm really curious about this issue but you have been a great help :)

Comment: @vendar123 If you are curious about it here's some reading for you: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/haslayout

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
 style="zoom:1; position:relative"
```

to the table elements fixed the issue as recommended by easwee